# Как собрать разные диапазоны (Массивы) в один? (Google Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Написал скрипт который копирует с одного листа на другой диапазон без пустых ячеек после последней заполненной строки. Но немогу понять как заставить работать скрипт с несколькими диапазонами пытался представить переменную example в виде массива - в журнале показывает массив из всех 4 диапазонов, но не выводит. Как заставить его вывести все 4 диапазона друг за другом в 1 диапазон ?

```
function Flat_data() {
var TARGETSHEET = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID листа на который собираем").getSheetByName("Test"); 
var SOURCESHEET = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID листа С которого собираем").getSheetByName("Client #1"); 

var source_last_row = SOURCESHEET.getLastRow();

SOURCESHEET.insertRowAfter(source_last_row);
var source_range1 = SOURCESHEET.getRange("G6:I"+(source_last_row)).getValues();
var source_range2 = SOURCESHEET.getRange("J6:L"+(source_last_row)).getValues();
var source_range3 = SOURCESHEET.getRange("N6:P"+(source_last_row)).getValues(); 
var source_range4 = SOURCESHEET.getRange("Q6:S"+(source_last_row)).getValues(); 

var example = (source_range1,source_range2,source_range3,source_range4);

Logger.log(example); 

var last_row = TARGETSHEET.getLastRow();

TARGETSHEET.insertRowAfter(last_row);

var newData = new Array();
  for(i in example){
    var row = example[i];
    var empty = false;
    for(i in example){
      if(row.toString() == ",,"){
        empty = true;
      }
    }
    if(!empty){
      newData.push(row);
    }
TARGETSHEET.getRange((last_row+1), 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, накосячил в массиве. Рабочий код надеюсь кому-то пригодиться:

```
function Flat_data() {
var TARGETSHEET = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID листа на который собираем").getSheetByName("Test"); 
var SOURCESHEET = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID листа С которого собираем").getSheetByName("Client #1"); 

var source_last_row = SOURCESHEET.getLastRow();

SOURCESHEET.insertRowAfter(source_last_row);
var source_range1 = SOURCESHEET.getRange("G6:I"+(source_last_row)).getValues();
var source_range2 = SOURCESHEET.getRange("J6:L"+(source_last_row)).getValues();
var source_range3 = SOURCESHEET.getRange("N6:P"+(source_last_row)).getValues(); 
var source_range4 = SOURCESHEET.getRange("Q6:S"+(source_last_row)).getValues(); 

var targetvalues = [];
targetvalues = source_range1.concat(source_range2,source_range3,source_range4);

//Logger.log(targetvalues);  

var last_row = TARGETSHEET.getLastRow();
TARGETSHEET.insertRowAfter(last_row);

var newData = new Array();
  for(i in targetvalues){
    var row = targetvalues[i];
    var empty = false;
    for(i in targetvalues){
      if(row.toString() == ",,"){
        empty = true;
      }
    }
    if(!empty){
      newData.push(row);
    }
// Logger.log(newData);  

}
TARGETSHEET.getRange("A"+(last_row+1)+":C"+(last_row+newData.length)).setValues(newData); // помещаем данные в целевую таблицу на последней строке

}
```